# ¿Cómo sustituir una columna por un dato parcial de otra columna?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id    producto   codigo          numero
1| botines | 140008        |ACO-140008-0200-0
2| remeras | 120014-138133 |ACT-120014-1381-0
3| medias  | 140007-885012 |ACO-140007-8850-0
4| buzo'   | 546455        |ACO-140007-0960-0
```

¿Qué funciones puedo usar para copiar de la columna `numero` los caracteres del 5 al 15, o sea `140008-0200` y reemplazarlo en la columna `codigo`, para que en lugar de `140008` sea `140008-0200`.

Muy agradecido .

Comment: podrias ser mas especifo en lo que quieres y definir mejor la situacion en la que te encuentras?

Comment: Por favor redacta un título objetivo, checa [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener una parte de la cadena almacenada en la columna de tu interés, puedes valerte de la función [`substring()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), que recibe como parámetros la cadena original, la posición de inicio y la longitud de la cadena a extraer. Así, si te interesa sustituir el valor en una sentencia `select`, podrías utilizar algo como:

```
select id, producto, substring(numero, 5, 11) as codigo, numero
  from MiTabla;
```

Si quieres que ese valor quede almacenado directamente en la columna, puedes entonces utilizar una sentencia [`update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), más o menos como:

```
update MiTabla
   set codigo = substring(numero, 5, 11);
```

Lo cual hará la sustitución en todas las filas actuales de la tabla.

Answer (score -1):

¿Te puedes referir a algo así?

```
SELECT *,
  SUBSTR(numero,5,11),
  REPLACE(codigo,
    SUBSTR(numero,5,6),
    SUBSTR(numero,5,11)
  )
  FROM productos;
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  producto varchar(15),
  codigo varchar(31),
  numero varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO productos (id, producto, codigo, numero) VALUES
  (1,'botines','140008','ACO-140008-0200-0'),
  (2,'remeras','120014-138133','ACT-120014-1381-0'),
  (3,'medias ','140007-885012','ACO-140007-8850-0'),
  (4,'buzo','546455','ACO-140007-0960-0');
```

Obtendrías:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 140008-0200         | 140008-0200                                                         |
|  2 | 120014-1381         | 120014-1381-138133                                                  |
|  3 | 140007-8850         | 140007-8850-885012                                                  |
|  4 | 140007-0960         | 546455                                                              |
+----+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```